# Is vanishing Gradient implies locally constant?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

It is given that $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^2)$ and $f$ is constant along one direction . At some point $(a,b)\ne (0,0)$ , function vanishes as well as its gradient vanishes . Can we conclude that function is at least locally constant there ?

Any Help/ Hint will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need the gradient to vanish on an open set, not just one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y)=x^2$ with $(a,b)=(0,0)$ satisfies your condition, but it doesn't seem to meet your expectations.

Comment: Can we create counterexample for points other than (0,0)?

Comment: @idon'tknow That looks like a completely immaterial detail. Once I have $f$, I can consider $f(v-v_0)$ and its bad point goes wherever I want.